# Can MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT be used with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, mediastore, android-fileprovider

```
public void startAudioIntent(){
    Intent audioIntent = new Intent();
    audioIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    audioIntent.setType("audio/*");
    mAudioFile = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(),"xyz");
    Log.d(TAG, "startAudioIntent: "+mAudioFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),"com.rgdgr8.beatbox.fileprovider",mAudioFile);
    audioIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri);
    List<ResolveInfo> audioActivities = getActivity()
            .getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(audioIntent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    for (ResolveInfo activity : audioActivities) {
        getActivity().grantUriPermission(activity.activityInfo.packageName,
                uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    }

    activityResultLauncher.launch(audioIntent);
}
```

I launch the implicit intent and I'm expecting to get the user selected file in my app's private files folder service by my FileProvider

```
activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getData()!=null && result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                        Uri uri = result.getData().getData();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+uri.getPath());
                        if (!isUsableAudio(uri.getPath())){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Add a .wav or .mp3 file only !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }

                        String path = getPath(uri);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+path);
                        int pos = mBeatBox.addSound(path);
                        adapter.notifyItemInserted(pos);

                        String fileName = mBeatBox.getSounds().get(pos).getFileNameWithExtension();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+fileName);
                        File renamedFile = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(),fileName);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+renamedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        if (!mAudioFile.renameTo(renamedFile))
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to rename file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Uri revokeUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), "com.rgdgr8.beatbox.fileprovider", mAudioFile);
                        getActivity().revokeUriPermission(revokeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    }
                }
            });
```

But I don't see any files in the desired location. I don't understand why.

Is MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT only usable with MediaStore actions?

Can I not use MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I not use MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Correct. `EXTRA_OUTPUT` is not mentioned in [the documentation for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_GET_CONTENT).

Comment: So, is there a constant like EXTRA_OUTPUT that works with ACTION_GET_CONTENT so that the selected file is directly copied to my fileprovider's serviced location? Or do I have to manually copy the file?

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly: "So, is there a constant like EXTRA_OUTPUT that works with ACTION_GET_CONTENT so that the selected file is directly copied to my fileprovider's serviced location?" -- no, sorry. "Or do I have to manually copy the file?" -- you need to manually copy the **content**. A `Uri` is not a file, and the `Uri` does not have to represent a file on the filesystem that your app can access. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`, passing in the `Uri`, to get an `InputStream` on the content that you can read from.